# Plotting InterpolatingFunction of a solution of Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method

I want the 3D surface plot of **-Log[sol[x,y,8]]** but I can't handle the **InterpolatingFunction** error. Please help me in extracting the function.

```
delt[x_, y_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{.5, 0}, {0, .5}}], {x, 
y}];
b=1; k=1;n=4;S=0.5;a=0.2;
FPE = \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) == s*\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) + s*\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) - \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((\((\((a*x^n)\)/\((S^n + x^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + y^n)\) - k*x)\)*p[x, y, t])\)\) - \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((\((\((\((a*y^n)\)/\((S^n + y^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + x^n)\) - k*y)\))\)*p[x, y, t])\)\);
s= .01;
sol = NDSolveValue[ {FPE,p[x, y, 0] == delt[x, y],
p[3, y, t] == 0,
p[0, y, t] == 0,
p[x, 0, t] == 0,
p[x, 3, t] == 0
},p, {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions"->MaxCellMeasure->0.0005}}];
plot3D[-Log[sol[x,y,8]],{x,0,3},{y,0,3},ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: Without taking the Log of `sol[x,y,8]`, the function plots fine (also p needs to be capitalized in Plot3D):

`Plot3D[sol[x, y, 8], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]`

If we look at `NMinValue[{sol[x, y,8], 0 <= x <= 3, 0 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}]` we see that `sol[x,y,8]` is negative at some points in the plot domain, so I thought maybe looking at `Log@Abs[sol[x,y,8]]` might be able to plot, or plotting `sol[x,y,8]` with "SignedLog" scaling on the z-axis would work, but it does not for me. 

`DiscretePlot` does work however: (cont'd in next comment)

Comment: `DiscretePlot3D[Log[Abs[sol[x, y, 8]]], {x, 0, 3, 0.01}, {y, 0, 3, 0.01}, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Joined -> True, Filling -> None]` 
Note I plot Log[Abs[sol[x,y,8]] since it is negative in parts of the domain.

Comment: @ydd thanks for the reply!  is it possible to ignore all negative values so that we can define Log? Also, I want to know how to extract the interpolating function in this case .

Comment: You could use `RealExponent[...]` instead which gives Log[Abs[...]]]:

`Plot3D[-RealExponent[sol[x, y, 8]], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 PlotPoints -> 100]` this plotted for me.

Comment: @ydd What is in the base of **RealExponent** (in my case I need **Log[x,e]**)? how to ignore the negative values of **sol[x,y,8]**

Comment: default base for `RealExponent` is base 10, while default for `Log` is base E. To change to base E, do RealExponent[x,E]. 

To completely ignore negative values,  you could clip values of sol[x,y,8] to be 0 when they are negative. This is really slow to plot with Plot3D however so I just make a table of values and ListPlot3D them:

`clipped[x_, y_] := Clip[sol[x, y, 8], {0, Infinity}];
cTab = Flatten[Table[{x, y, -Log[clipped[x, y]]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.01}, {y, 0, 3, 0.01}], 1];
ListPlot3D[cTab, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2:  Added code to back-substitute numerical solution into DE**

**Edit1:  Changed after studying solution**

Plotting sol[x,y,8] below one sees it begins very small oscillations  between positive and negative values assuming the machine-precision FEM method employed yields and accurate solution and the oscillations aren't spurious.  One could back-substitue the solution to check this.  Assuming the solution is indeed correct, then this is  of course problematic if one is interested in taking the log of the solution unless further processing of the solution is acceptable such as using absolute values or other methods.

[image]

[image]

**Back-substitution of solution into DE:**

```
 (* compute solution with cell measure=0.0005 *)

 cellMeasure = 0.0005;
delt[x_, y_] := 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}], {x, 
    y}]; 
b = 1; k = 1; n = 4; S = 1/2; a = 2/10;
FPE = \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) == s*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) + s*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((\((\((a*x^n)\)/\((S^n + 
            x^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + y^n)\) - k*x)\)*
       p[x, y, t])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((\((\((\((a*y^n)\)/\((S^n + 
             y^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + x^n)\) - k*y)\))\)*
       p[x, y, t])\)\);
s = 1/100;
sol = NDSolveValue[ {FPE, p[x, y, 0] == delt[x, y],
    p[3, y, t] == 0,
    p[0, y, t] == 0,
    p[x, 0, t] == 0,
    p[x, 3, t] == 0
    }, p, {t, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 3}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> cellMeasure}}];
```

Now plot p(x,y,t) and a yellow trace of p(x,0.8,8) just for visualization:

```
(* Plot magnified solution and a yellow trace of the solution \
p(x,0.8,8) *)  

trace1 = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{x, 0.8, sol[x, 0.8, 8]}, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> Yellow, PlotRange -> All];
 magPlot = 
  Plot3D[sol[x, y, 8], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 250, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Magnified Plot", 16, Bold, Black], 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16, Bold, Black], 
     Style["y", 16, Bold, Black], Style["p(x,y,8)", 16, Bold, Black]},
    ClippingStyle -> None];
Show[{magPlot, trace1}]
```

[image]

Now compare the left side of the DE with the right side of the DE at the point (1.2,0.8,8) along the yellow trace (or any other point (x,y,8) and print the values:

```
tVal = 8;
yVal = .8;
xVal = 1.2;
leftSide = (\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) //. {p -> sol, 
     x -> xVal, y -> yVal, t -> tVal});
rightSide = (s*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, x\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) + s*\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y, y\)]\(p[x, y, t]\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\((\((\((a*x^n)\)/\((S^n + 
             x^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + y^n)\) - k*x)\)*
        p[x, y, t])\)\) - \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]\((\((\((\((a*y^n)\)/\((S^n + 
              y^n)\) + \((b*S^n)\)/\((S^n + x^n)\) - k*y)\))\)*
        p[x, y, t])\)\)) //. {p -> sol, x -> xVal, y -> yVal, 
    t -> tVal};

Print["Left side: ", leftSide];
Print["Right side: ", rightSide];

(* Left side: -3.92564*10^-7 *)

(* Right side: 0.0000816017 *)
```

The difference is not small.  I'm not proficient with PDEs and now sure why.  You should be able to study this code and test it at other points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In your answer, you told about the back-substitute to check if the solution is correct. can you please tell me how to do it? Is the 2nd plot is log plot of the solution?

Comment: @Gitsagar:  The plots are $p(x,y,t)$.  I'll update my post above to show how to back-substitute the solution into the PDE.